# How Can Show Category in custom post type

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

```
<?php 

   register_post_type(
   'comet_portfulio', array( 
    'labels'    =>  array(
            'name'  =>  'Portfulios',
            'add_new'   =>  'Add New Portfulio',
            'Add_new_item'  =>  'Add New Portfulio' ,
        ),
    'public'    => true, 
    'supports'  =>  array('title','thumbnail','editor'),
    'rewrite'   =>  array(
        'slug'  =>  'portfulio' 
    ),
    'menu_icon' =>  'dashicons-portfolio',
 ));

 // Register Portfulio Taxonimy

 register_taxonomy(
  'portfulio_cat','comet_portfulio', array( 
    'labels'    =>  array(
            'name'  =>  'Catagory',
            'add_new'   =>  'Add New catagory',
            'Add_new_item'  =>  'Add New Catagoer' ,
        ),
    'public'        => true,  
    'hierarchical'  =>  true,
 ));
```

?>

Comment: Okay.... I see a lot of categories

Comment: Can you provide any additional details? I'm unsure what you're asking.